# How can I show `ispell-word` choices at bottom of the buffer?

Tags: ispell

When I run `ispell-word` it suggests word at the top of the buffer, like:

[image]

Instead can we show the options at the bottom of the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try modifying `ispell-display-buffer`. There are two instances of the symbol `above` used in that function. Copy the function to a different file `my-ispell-display-buffer.el`, change `above` to `below` in the two instances (and also in the doc string of the function), evaluate it with `C-x C-e` and try `ispell`ing something.

If you like it, add a `provides` to the bottom of the file:

```el
;;; modified version of ispell-display-buffer to display it
;;; below the buffer.
(defun ispell-display-buffer (buffer)
   ...
 )

(provides 'my-ispell-display-buffer)
```

and `require` it in your init file *after* loading the normal `ispell`:

```el
...
(eval-after-load 'ispell (require 'my-ispell-display-buffer))
```

That will override the built-in function with your modified one. If
you don't like it, get rid of the above line and (optionally) delete the `my-ispell-display-buffer.el` file.

EDIT: I should say that if you do the above, you will have forked Emacs. That's usually a bad idea, but this is a specialized function that will probably not cause any problems. You might still want to keep an eye on any changes to it just in case there are bugs that are fixed with it. Your version will not pick up these changes, so it will be up to you to keep things in sync.